# Javascript scoping of Ember objects

Tags: javascript, ember.js, scoping

I am not sure of the difference between the following:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

    errors: {},

    performPermalinkUpdate: function(){

        let errors = this.get('errors');

        this.requestPermalink(this.get('title'), this.endpoint).then((resp) => {    
            // Do success stuff
        }).catch((resp) => {
            Ember.set(errors, 'permalink', "Test");
        });
    }
});
```

VS

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

    errors: {},

    performPermalinkUpdate: function(){

        this.requestPermalink(this.get('title'), this.endpoint).then((resp) => {    
            // Do success stuff
        }).catch((resp) => {
            let errors = this.get('errors');
            Ember.set(errors, 'permalink', "Test");
        });
    }
});
```

The first one does not actually alter the `errors` property.  The error never shows up on the template.  Whereas the second will and the resulting error shows up on my template.

I assume I am missing a key scoping issue with the promise.

Comment: When and where and how is the `errors` property set? Is it perhaps set inside `requestPermalink`?

Comment: Updated w/ more of the component containing the function

Comment: for the first instead of `let` if you say `var` ?  does it make any sense here.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the timing. The first one is accessing the `errors` object earlier, before calling `requestPermalink`. The last one access it after. The `this` context is the same because of the arrow function.

---

I assume your `requestPermalink` function does something like this:

```
requestPermalink() {
  // 
  this.set('errors', { debug: "second error object" });
},
```

Then your order of execution for the first example is:

1. `this.errors` is `{}` because thats how you initialized it with `errors: {},`.
2. you execute `let errors = this.get('errors');`. So now the `errors` variable is the same object as `this.errors`.
3. You call `this.requestPermalink`. This will execute the `this.set('errors', { debug: "second error object" });` I've posted above. Now `this.errors` is that new object with `debug: "second error object"` defined, while the `errors` variable is still pointing to the original object `{}`.
4. Next you execute `Ember.set(errors, 'permalink', "Test");`. This will change the `errors` variable from `{}` to `{permalink: "Test"}`. However `this.errors` is still `{ debug: "second error object" }`.

The order of execution for the second example however:

1. `this.errors` is `{}` because thats how you initialized it with `errors: {},`.
2. You call `this.requestPermalink`. This will execute the `this.set('errors', { debug: "second error object" });` I've posted above. 
   Now `this.errors` is that new object with `debug: "second error object"` defined. However there is no `errors` variable yet, so probably the original object `{}` can be garbage collected.
3. You execute `let errors = this.get('errors');`. Now `errors` is the same as object as `this.errors` and looks like  `{ debug: "second error object" }`.
4. You modify `errors` with `Ember.set(errors, 'permalink', "Test");`. Because `errors` and `this.errors` are both references to the same object this will modify `this.errors`.

Comment: And this explains the behavior reported by the OP how?

Comment: Since the `this` context is the same in both areas where `let errors = this.get('errors')`, I would assume that the errors object would be updated regardless of when the errors object is accessed.  If I am right in assuming this, why is the errors object not updated in the first example?

Comment: why should it get updated? If you do `foo=this.bar;this.bar="blu";` then you wouldn't expect `foo` to have the value `"blu"` right?

Comment: Yes, but then why does the second example update things as I'd expect?

Comment: I tried to explain it step by step. Can you follow?